# Find all products in user cart table and check if product is in saved items table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm practicing my (beginner) skills on a Shopping site with NodeJS, MySQL and React. I need to query the Database to select products from the users cart table, the product details (image, name, amount in stock e.t.c) from the products table and check if the product is saved (in the saved table)

Here is the schema for the tables:

- **Products**

`id | Name | Price | Description | Vendor | Tag | Rating | Image | AmountInStock`

- **Saved**

`id | user_ID | product_id`

- **Cart**

`id | user_ID | product_id`

Here is the query I have written so far:

```
SELECT c.id, p.name as product_name, c.user_id, c.product_id,
  COUNT(c.product_id) as product_count, p.price, p.description, 
  p.vendor, p.tag, p.rating, p.image, p.amountInStock, 
  COUNT(s.product_id) as inSaved
FROM cart c, products p, saved s
WHERE p.id = c.product_id
AND C.user_id = '13'
GROUP BY c.product_id, c.user_id
HAVING COUNT(c.product_id) > 0;
```

Comment: You haven't provided any *Schema*, you've just listed the column names; providing a schema would be the *create table* statements including the data types, defaults, key, constraints etc.

Comment: show us your desired output

Comment: You hit the `comma` key way too many times.  This inevitably causes `JOIN` mistakes.  Write queries with joins more like this: `SELECT ... FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ... JOIN t3 ON ... etc;`  If you do that, you will notice the missing `s` logic.  There are other design issues.  But that's one of the main issues with your current statement. Also, look into `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`, which will help with the *is / is not saved* logic.

Answer (score 0):

Without any testing i would try something like this:

```
SELECT c.id, p.name as product_name, c.user_id, c.product_id,
  COUNT(c.product_id) as product_count, p.price, p.description, 
  p.vendor, p.tag, p.rating, p.image, p.amountInStock, 
  COUNT(s.product_id) as inSaved, s.product_id
FROM cart c, products p, saved s
LEFT JOIN saved 
ON(p.id=s.id)
WHERE c.product_id= s.product_id
AND C.user_id = '13'
GROUP BY c.product_id, c.user_id
HAVING COUNT(c.product_id) > 0;
```

So the key is the LEFT JOIN. Every id whos in the first table gets linked with the second table. If there is null, the product isnt saved, if there is an id, the product is saved.

Its untested, but in theory i thinks its the way to go.